# IDEA 10.0.3 replaces declarations with fully qualified names on refactoring

Tags: java, import, refactoring, intellij-idea, move

Whenever I move a (unambiguously named) type to another package, IDEA decides to replace all occurrences of given type with its fully qualified name instead of just adding the appropriate imports; going through all affected files and manually fixing the imports is madness.

I tried out all possible combinations of the "Auto Import" settings to no effect. Has anybody run into the same problem?

Comment: No, but the best people to ask would be Jetbrains. I find they usually respond within a day. Which version are you using? It could be a bug which is now fixed.

Comment: I'm using 10.0.3. Unfortunately I can't update due to the unavailability of some plugins I need for newer versions of IDEA. Thanks for the tip though, I'll ask the Jetbrains people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall similar issue reported at least once, however the user was not able to reproduce it with a new project and could not provide his real project affected by this bug.

This issue seems to be caused by some specific project configuration which is very unusual and therefore not affecting the majority of IDEA users.

If you have a reproducible test case, please [file a bug to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) and attach your project to the issue so that we can investigate and fix it.

P.S. also try IDEA 10.5.1 since you are using an old version, upgrade is free for you.

Comment: I asked on the Jetbrains forums as well and it seems that the issue is triggered (only?) when dragging and dropping the class in the project view, but not when using Refactor -> Move. Indeed, Refactor -> Move seems to not be affected by this issue, but there was a glitch there as well, where the fqn was added to a **getter** returning the moved type, but otherwise it looked good. On the second try it seemed to work. Seems to be a pretty obscure bug, yea, I'll try to create a repro when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that "Use fully qualified class names" checkbox is disabled in Settings>CodeStyle>Imports.  I apologize if that was a no brainer and you've already tried it.

Comment: Unfortunately I've disabled it but please do not apologize :)

Answer (score 0):

May be there exist two imports with same names ? Have you checked this issue ?

Also please specify IntelliJ IDEA's version.

Comment: No, the type is unambiguously named :/ Version added.

Comment: So just to be clear.  You have a class named Foo in com.mystuff.util package.  You have another class named Bar which has a Foo member variable.  You then move Foo to com.mystuff.pojo and Intellij is modifying the reference in Bar from:    private Foo foo;    to    private com.mystuff.pojo.Foo foo;